# How to join random lines, defined by two points, into a single path? A traveling salesman like problem

Tags: python, concatenation, traveling-salesman

I am attempting to generate at single continuous line from a set of lines that have been defined by two points. 
Currently I generate a subset of random lines as follows:

> [ [0, 0] [2, 2], [2, 1] [0, 1], [0, 1] [2, 2], ... ]

Next, I want to trace along these lines to make the longest unbroken path possible. Since there would be hundreds to thousands of these lines some will end up not be connected which is okay. The reason being that they can have the following properties among each other:

> 1. Same starting point
> 2. Same ending point
> 3. Same starting and ending point

The resulting output will look like a matrix which traces the optimal path that should be taken such as:

> [ [0, 0], [2, 2], [0, 1], [2, 1] ]

I don't care to optimize the path length (because the length will already be predefined by the total length of the lines that were produced) but I would like to minimize the number of break points. Also the continuous line does not have to start and end at the same position.

Coding in python I initially started from the guide [here](https://ericphanson.com/blog/2016/the-traveling-salesman-and-10-lines-of-python/) I can use an array of arrays as my "cities". I'm not sure that this is the best method since it is trying to reduce the distance. Therefore, I feel like there might be a similar problem for analysis of genetic sequencing data; having many fragments which must be aligned to form a continuous stretch of DNA.

Ultimately I am looking for any suggestions on aligning these paths into a single continuous stretch using previously published python packages. In the end, should I code this myself, I will publish my results here.

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem definition or see the comparison to it and genome assembly but if you think it will help you can look up deBrujin graphs. This is a nice introduction. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-ecmECK7lw . Also, the networkx library https://networkx.github.io/ might be useful, but again I'm not clear on the problem defintion.

Comment: Thanks @sintribu I will look into using deBrujin graphs. I googled up the networkx documentation and it may work for my needs. In that search I also found [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) which seems to provide similar function but in a more "efficient" manner. I'll do some tests and see what I can't come up with!